# Java Strategygame: Units-Coordination and Behaviour

Tags: java

on a 100x50 orthogonal tilegrid with 32x32 tiles, i created some animated Units, which are moved by A* (like in many strategy games usual) with a rightclick on the mouse.

The collision detection works by using a two dimensional booleanarray i gave the grid in the constructor and this says whether a tile is an obstacle or not.

Thats what i have so far and it works.

I am now figuring out, some Kind of Units coordinationsystem, which simply doesnt allows the Units to walk into each other. All of this just should be in this 32x32 tilesized RASTER not more for the moment.

I just thought this should be easy, but the grid is loaded once just like the obstacles, while the Units positions are always different and the Problem here is, that if i define each unit as an obstacle at Runtime, the obstacle at its Position stays stored in the gridarray and it stay some Kind of invisible obstacle, although it shouldnt be one. The result is, that the unit cant go the way back, where it cames from. Another Problem is of Course, that a unit can stand still or move arround(so far) and if it moves arround ist not rastered anymore.

My question now is: How can i implement a movable obstacle or do i have to implement a separate collision detection for my Units here?

PS: The Programm is quite big and i dont like to post the whole Code, although that would make all easier for u guys to help me, but if somebody understand what i mean, i can post the relevant Code snippets here on the Forum.

Comment: Just don't use a boolean grid but something more sophisticated, e.g. references to objects that can block the tile. Obstacles and units would be such objects with obstacles being static. When calculating the path you just consider all blocking objects _except_ the unit that is moving (which obviously can't block itself).

Comment: So i treat a tile and a unit separately as an obstacle/non-obstacle, by defining it in Constructor?